# PulseAudio: All input audio goes to output

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio

Please bear with me as I'm still new to this.
My current issue is that all audio on the XR18, be it TRAX as well as PC audio output goes to Discord.

I am unable to figure this out on my own and need proper guidance.

Results of `pacmd list-sinks` :

```
pacmd list-sinks
2 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.usb-BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9-00.multichannel-output>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9040
    volume: front-left: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   front-right: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   rear-left: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   rear-right: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   front-center: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   lfe: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   side-left: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   side-right: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux0: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux1: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux2: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux3: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux4: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux5: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux6: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux7: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux8: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   aux9: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 16.77 ms
    max request: 25 KiB
    max rewind: 25 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s32le 18ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe,side-left,side-right,aux0,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6,aux7,aux8,aux9
    used by: 1
    linked by: 53
    configured latency: 7.52 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.usb-BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9-00>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "32"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "X18/XR18"
        alsa.long_card_name = "BEHRINGER X18/XR18 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2.1:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1397"
        device.vendor.name = "BEHRINGER International GmbH"
        device.product.id = "00d4"
        device.product.name = "X18/XR18"
        device.serial = "BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9"
        device.string = "hw:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "6912000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "3456000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "multichannel-output"
        device.profile.description = "Multichannel"
        device.description = "X18/XR18 Multichannel"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 39321 /  60% / -13.31 dB,   front-right: 39321 /  60% / -13.31 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 32.28 ms
    max request: 6 KiB
    max rewind: 6 KiB
    monitor source: 2
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 9
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC3246 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC3246 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf428000 irq 139"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a171"
        device.product.name = "CM238 HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
----------------
Source #0
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.usb-BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9-00.multichannel-output.monitor
    Description: Monitor of X18/XR18 Multichannel
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s32le 18ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe,side-left,side-right,aux0,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6,aux7,aux8,aux9
    Owner Module: 8
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   front-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   rear-left: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   rear-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   front-center: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   lfe: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   side-left: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   side-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux0: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux1: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux2: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux3: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux4: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux5: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux6: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux7: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux8: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   aux9: 0 /   0% / -inf dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.usb-BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9-00.multichannel-output
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 40000 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of X18/XR18 Multichannel"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "X18/XR18"
        alsa.long_card_name = "BEHRINGER X18/XR18 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2.1:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1397"
        device.vendor.name = "BEHRINGER International GmbH"
        device.product.id = "00d4"
        device.product.name = "X18/XR18"
        device.serial = "BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9"
        device.string = "1"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #2
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 9
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 40000 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf428000 irq 139"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a171"
        device.product.name = "CM238 HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #3
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_input.usb-BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9-00.multichannel-input
    Description: X18/XR18 Multichannel
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s32le 18ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe,side-left,side-right,aux0,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6,aux7,aux8,aux9
    Owner Module: 8
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   front-right: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   rear-left: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   rear-right: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   front-center: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   lfe: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   side-left: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   side-right: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux0: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux1: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux2: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux3: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux4: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux5: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux6: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux7: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux8: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB,   aux9: 14204 /  22% / -39.84 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 2348 usec, configured 30000 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "32"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "X18/XR18"
        alsa.long_card_name = "BEHRINGER X18/XR18 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2.1:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1397"
        device.vendor.name = "BEHRINGER International GmbH"
        device.product.id = "00d4"
        device.product.name = "X18/XR18"
        device.serial = "BEHRINGER_X18_XR18_6CFB9FF9"
        device.string = "hw:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "6912000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "3456000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "multichannel-input"
        device.profile.description = "Multichannel"
        device.description = "X18/XR18 Multichannel"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Formats:
        pcm
```

As you can see there are 18 channels.
I also see that all output from the desktop goes to the Aux channels in X-Air.

How do I stop this and make it work properly like this?

- USB in 15/16 audio from desktop
- Left/Right Main to Desktop Input over USB ( This is the Main Mix that comes out the Sound Desk.)